# AngularJS validation not working

Tags: angularjs

I've created a form with angularjs, but when I first load the page, the form starts out invalid and the entire form turns red. I've added "novalidate" to the form and "required" to an input, yet the whole form starts our invalid and red.

Comment: [`ng-dirty`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) is set on a field if it has been modified.

Comment: What's your question? If a field is required, and nothing has been entered in the field, it's expected to be invalid. The contrary would be a problem.

Comment: Why does the form start out invalid? It should be valid until I enter something "invalid" into the form. The whole thing starts out angry red and invalid.

Answer (score 0):

From this program when you are clicking submit button without entering any values validation will happen

```
<form name="product_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
            <div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && product_form.emailid.$invalid]">
                <form-element label="Name" mod="product">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="name" ng-model="product.name" ng-disabled="product.id" required/>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-show="submitted && product_form.name.$error.required"> Please enter name </span>
                </form-element>

                <form-element label="Emailid" mod="product">
                    <input type="email" name="emailid" class="form-control" placeholder="emailid" ng-model="product.emailid" required>
                    <span ng-show="submitted && product_form.emailid.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter emailid</span>
                </form-element>

                <form-element label="Password" mod="product">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="product.password" required/>    
                    <span ng-show="submitted && product_form.password.$error.required" class="help-block"> Please enter password </span>
                </form-element> 
            </div>  

            <div class="space"></div>
            <div class="space-4"></div>  

            <div class="modal-footer">  

                <a class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="cancel()" ><i class="ace-icon fa fa-reply"></i> Cancel </a>

                 <button ng-click="saveProduct(product);submitted=true"
                            ng-enabled="product_form.$invalid || enableUpdate"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ng-binding"
                            type="submit">
                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i>Submit
                 </button>


            </div>
     </form>
```